# SQL: Are Searches Faster at Identifying Distinct Rows If More Attributes Are Tested?

Tags: sql

Given a large database table, and the foreknowledge that a unique row with qualities you know is in there, can the row be retrieved faster if more attributes are tested for known values?  Or, will the search be as fast as finding the one row with the one field that holds the unique value you expect to be there?

For example, if you had 35 columns on the table, and you knew the values you expected in 34 of those columns, and you knew that there was a unique ID to be found in one of them, would it pay to list all of the known attributes in the SELECT?

If it does, how large or varied would the database have to be in order for the time to search to show a clear reduction?

Would it pay to use subqueries to eliminate unwanted entries early?

Just curious.

Comment: Are you referring to a table with no primary key and no indexes?

Comment: Effectively, yeah.  A PK could exist, but it would not be in use for the SELECT.

Comment: You have to test this one. Most databases can provide an execution plan for your query.

Comment: The speed of the query is going to greatly vary based on whether you are using `=`, `LIKE`, or `IN()` clauses within your where clause. This will also be affected by the average size, and type of the data within those 35 columns. There is absolutely ZERO chance of anyone providing any useful insight unless this table is already built and you can provide more information. In general if you can use 3 fields in the where clause to return the same number of rows as 34 fields then the 3-field where clause will perform better (I caution you to take that with a grain of salt).

Comment: OK, I'll consider the question closed.  Have a nice day.